# Segfault 11 when initializing large arrays dynamically

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault

Hi I'm using C for a school assignment. I have to apologize that I've got very rusty with low-level languages like C. When I try to initialize some arrays dynamically, my code gives me segfault 11 when n>100. I tried to fire up Valgrind to understand what has happened, but I can't quite understand the debug log as the memory block it reports is much less than that I intended to allocate at a large n value. Could anyone kindly help to see what is wrong? Thank you!

My code (the error happens when I set each entry of the 2D matrix to 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int n;

typedef struct{
  float x;
  float y;
} Point2D;

float rand_float(){
    return (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
}
int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    scanf("%d", &n);
    

    int (*adjm)[n][n] = malloc( sizeof(float[n][n])+1 );
    Point2D (*vcoord)[n] = malloc( sizeof(Point2D[n])+1 ); 
    
    // initialize coords
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        (*vcoord[i]).x  = rand_float();
        (*vcoord[i]).y  = rand_float();
        printf("%d %f %f \n", i, (*vcoord[i]).x, (*vcoord[i]).y);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < n; y++){
             *adjm[x][y] = 1;
        }
    }
    
    // free up memory
    free(*adjm);
    free(*vcoord);
    return 0;

}
```

First few lines of Valgrind log when I let n=200:

```
==18832== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18832== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPLd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18832== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18832== Command: ./out
==18832== Parent PID: 1670
==18832==
==18832== Invalid write of size 4
==18832==    at 0x1089F4: main (in /home/usrname/valgrindtest/out)
==18832==  Address 0x5257050 is 1,600 bytes inside a block of size 1,601 alloc'd
==18832==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18832==    by 0x1089B8: main (in /home/usrname/valgrindtest/out)
==18832==
==18832== Invalid write of size 4
==18832==    at 0x108A23: main (in /home/usrname/valgrindtest/out)
==18832==  Address 0x5257054 is 3 bytes after a block of size 1,601 alloc'd
==18832==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
```

Comment: `int (*adjm)[n][n] = malloc( sizeof(float[n][n])+1 );`: looks like you mean `int` instead of `float`?

Comment: `free(*adjm);` etc is wrong; the pointer returned by `malloc` is in `adjm`, not in `*adjm`.  Should be `free(adjm); free(vcoord);`

Comment: Thanks so much! I changed int to float but segfault still appeared at the same spot. And also thanks for pointing out that wrong usage of free(.)...I really need to brush up these a bit.

Comment: And most importantly, `malloc(sizeof(float[n][n])+1)` does not allocate the matrix as you expect. `sizeof(float[n][n])` is equal to `sizeof(float*)` which is probably 8, therefore 9 bytes (always) in total.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan Hmmm I printf-ed the sizeof that array, and seems it's dynamic and actually depends on n? That +1 is just a fudge I added as I don't know why I'm having segfault before.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan: That's not correct.  `float[n][n]` is not itself a pointer, and decay does not happen here.  The `+1` however doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @NateEldredge My bad, guess I need to refresh my C as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  `(*vcoord[i]).x  = rand_float();`:  The `[]` operator has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the dereference `*`, so what you need here is `(*vcoord)[i].x`.  Otherwise you are treating `vcoord` as an array of arrays of size `n`, and using the `i`th element of that array, which is out of bounds.  Similarly for all other uses of `vcoord` and `adjm`, which would need to be `(*adjm)[i][j]`.

This explains the 1600: a `Point2D` is most likely 8 bytes on your platform, so `Point2D[200]` is 1600 bytes.  Thus `vcoord[1]` refers to element 1 of an array of these 1600-byte arrays, which is at offset 1600 from the base address `vcoord` - right off the end.

Other less harmful bugs:

1. `int (*adjm)[n][n] = malloc( sizeof(float[n][n])+1 );` : `float` should be `int` here, and the `+1` serves no purpose.  (Probably not the cause of your crash, since `float` and `int` have the same size on most common platforms.)  Many people prefer to avoid the possibility of such a mismatch by writing `malloc(sizeof(*adjm))` instead.
2. `free(*adjm);`: The pointer allocated by `malloc` is in the variable `adjm`, not within the array to which it points.  Make this `free(adjm);` and likewise `free(vcoord);` on the next line.  It shouldn't actually have any effect, though, since `*adjm` is the array to which `adjm` points, and this decays back into a pointer to the same address.

Note that you have chosen a complicated way of writing your code here.  The normal way to allocate a 1D array like `vcoord` is to use, not a pointer to an array, but a pointer to the object type in question, and use `malloc` to create the array for it to point into.  So a more typical way to write this would be

```
Point2D *vcoord = malloc(n * sizeof(Point2D));  // or (n * sizeof *vcoord)
vcoord[i].x = rand_float();
free(vcoord);
```

Likewise, for the 2D array `adjm`, don't use a pointer to a 2D array, but rather a pointer into an array of 1D arrays.  So

```
int (*adjm)[n] = malloc(n * sizeof(int[n]));
// or: (n * sizeof *adjm)
// or even: (n * n * sizeof(int))
adjm[x][y] = 1;
free(adjm);
```

This avoids the need for the tricky dereference of the 2D array pointer and makes the syntax much simpler.

Comment: Thank you! That's a sneaky bug... I wasn't paying much attention to where I put the brackets - certainly have to be more careful next time.  Edit: I fixed the brackets as you suggested and now the code is working fine. An additional question, may I ask where that 1600 bytes is coming from in Valgrind, when I try to use n=200 to debug?

Comment: @Macrophage: See edit, including some other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Yes, my code is awkward, but now I understand these better.

Comment: @M.M So did he forgot a = there? Also, should I use vcoord = malloc(...) or a pointer *vcoord = malloc(...), which one is the best practice?

Comment: @Macrophage: You can't do `Point2D vcoord = malloc(...);`. It doesn't make sense and won't even compile; `malloc` returns a pointer and it must be assigned to a pointer.

Comment: @NateEldredge That makes sense. I was reminded that it is actually the pointer to the first value that get stored in an array. So using *ptr = malloc to dynamically create array makes sense, and I shouldn't have that [n] from (*ptr)[n] in my code.